# python package management for python 2.7 and python 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.5, package-management

I have both python 2.7 and 3.5 installed(3.5 is the default one), and I am using pycharm as IDE.
I am having hard time to install packages for 2.7 because it isn't the default environment. When I use pip install, it always installs package for 3.5. If I use pycharm package manager, I don't know how to install custom packages that is not in the repo.

My question is:
When I have 2 version of python installed, how do I install packages only for one environment or the other, and how do I install packages for both environment?

Thanks

Comment: This is what [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io) is for.

Comment: Can you give a syntax for installing a package for python 2.7 and a syntax for installing a package for python 3.5? I couldn't figure it out. I always do pip install package.

Comment: Use `pip2` for Py2 and `pip3` for Py3. Easy.

Comment: I tried pip2 and pip3. They aren't recognized as valid command. Do I need to set anything up for pip?

Comment: What operating system are you running? What is the output of `pip -V`? Also, what is the output of `python -V` and `python3 -V`?

Comment: 1. windows 7  
2. pip -V = pip 8.1.1 from C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)
3. python -V = Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)
4. python3 -V = 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
5. python2 -V = 'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command

thanks for the help